# build a linear regressor with labels in different scales

Tags: regression, machine-learning, multiple-regression, linear-model, bias

I just ran into this linear regression problem where the labels are in entirely different range for example for 25% of the samples, the labels are in [0.001,0.01], then for another 25 % of the samples, the labels are in [100, 1000] and then for another quarter the labels are in [10000, 1000000] and for the last quarter of the samples, the labels are in the range [10000000, 10000000000].

Now the linear regression model I try to build remains biased towards one of the scale values, for example, even when the predictions should be in the range [0.001, 0.01], the model predicts it in the range of [10000, 1000000].

How to solve such problems ? clearly the model weights are drawn in favor of larger labels

Comment: Why do the labels differ? What is the data? Are those bounds known or observed from data?

Comment: the labels come as a part of the dataset itself; so virtually no control over it

Comment: yes, as the labels are coming from the data, the bounds are known

Comment: What are the labels so they can differ so much? It'd be easier to answer your question if you told us more about your data, as the answer would probably depend on the details of your data.

Comment: actually the data is coming from some astronomical source; not sure about the description of the dataset. currently i just have features and corresponding labels

Comment: something related to red shift